# split navbar into 2 parts

Tags: html

So I got this header, I want the logo in the middle, and then 2 links on the left and 2 links on the right. I guess I know how to do this but not what the best way is. Got what I think that works below. Edit: Obviously no css applied yet, gotta get the  html straight first.

So here's the header

```
    <header>
        <div id="head-wrap">
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="smartphones.php">Smartphones</a></li>
                <li><a href="tablets.php">Tablets</a></li>
                <li><a href="laptops.php">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="desktops.php">Desktops</a></li>
              </ul>         
            </nav>
        </div>  
    </header>
```

What might work

```
    <header>
        <div id="head-wrap">
            <nav>
                <div id="nav-left>
                   <ul>
                     <li><a href="smartphones.php">Smartphones</a></li>
                     <li><a href="tablets.php">Tablets</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>

                <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" height="42" width="42">

                <div id="nav-right">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a href="laptops.php">Laptops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="desktops.php">Desktops</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>          
            </nav>
        </div>  
    </header>
```

Is this the best way or should I do it differently?

Regards

Comment: If that works for you it's fine. Another alternative would be to make the logo the bg of a middle `li`. BTW, your HTML is invalid. you need to remove the divs surrounding the `li` and replacement with `ul`'

Comment: +1 I was wondering how to do this using WordPress when the page list is generated dynamically, making it less convenient to use two `div`s for the left and right sides.

Comment: Your HTML code is not valid. `<li>` must be a child of either `<ul>` or `<ol>`. Swap the divs for `<ul id="nav-left">` and `<ul id="nav-right">` and you'll be moving in the right direction.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry about that, I just forgot the ul. These would still be inside the left and right div though. I'm really just wondering if this is a proper way or if there's a different, better way to achieve this. Thanks for the response

Comment: @OllyHodgson I had just forgotten to add the ul, edited that. But I guess the way you put it would be the proper way

Comment: I don't think there is a semantical answer for this.  Just be sure to keep to correctly formatted HTML and the rest is up to your preferences.  As far as CSS goes, it depends on your desired outcome.  For centering it all, use `display:inline-block`.  For left and right, use floats.

Comment: @OllyHodgson Also, can I put my logo inside the <nav> or should I put it below it? Sorry for these dumb questions but I'm just trying to learn

Comment: nav is just for a list of major navigation links.  Because the logo is usually linked to the root of your doc, I think it's perfectly fine to have your linked logo in the nav element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example has a lot of superfluous HTML elements in it. Instead of multiple `div` containers, try something like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="smartphones.php">Smartphones</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="tablets.php">Tablets</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" height="42" width="42" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="laptops.php">Laptops</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="desktops.php">Desktops</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then `display` the `li` elements `inline`:

```
li{
    display:inline;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/B5j7v/)

Obviously you'll need to edit this more to fit your own needs, but a simple structure is the start of a good design.

Comment: Didn't think of adding the img in an li also. This seems pretty good. Can I add a class to the left 2 links, and a different class to the right ones so style them differently? Or is that not-done?

Comment: I like this answer.  Much cleaner and no need for two navs.  The only problem I can see with it, and with the idea in general (OP's aswell) is when more links are added to the nav(s) and the logo is off centre and the possibility that the layout breaks

Comment: @user5623896726 How would you fix that then? Cause I might add more links in the future

Comment: @user5623896726 That's obviously a problem with symmetrically balanced layouts. The only solution is to use equal amounts of links on either side of the image. Give each `li` element a set width as well, then center the text, so that you will get a consistent width on either side (determined by the number of links).